# Carrying out a random-number generator x number of times based on user input

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator, user-input

I am trying to make a random number generator with numbers 1-10 in Python, and I'd like it to generate a certain number of responses based on how many instances the user wants it. For example, the output for 5 responses would go something like this: 6, 1, 2, 9, 10, with each of those being randomly generated. Repeats are ok.

This is all I have so far (I'm not that experienced):

```
import random

x = int(input("How many times? "))

y = random.randint(0,10)
```

...and that's as much as I have. Please help!

Comment: Throw the `y=...` statement into a loop that iterates `x` times.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

z = int(input("How many times? "))

for x in range(0, z):
   print "%d\n" % random.randint(1,10)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant! So simple/awesome. I was overthinking it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :).

Also you if you want 1-10, you may want to use random.randint(1,10) as I believe randint is an inclusive function (I edited my post for it)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `x` as both the number of iterations and the iteration value.

Comment: Agreed, fixed my answer

Comment: Since you're not using the value of `x` now, why not use `_`?  That's what it's for.

Comment: I've never coded in python. Just was helping out with an example that I knew would work 100%

Answer (score 2):

After, getting the input from the user, run a loop x number of times and print a random output to the screen:

```
import random

x = int(input('How many times?'))

for _ in range(x):
    print random.randint(1, 10)
```

Also, if you are using python 2.x, use the raw_input function instead of input.

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensions are also good.  They are much faster than loops, though in this case that is of no importance.

```
[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(x)]
```

For x =7, this generates a list of seven random numbers between 1 and 10:

```
[5, 6, 4, 7, 7, 10, 5]
```